# c/c++ get large size data like 180 array from another class in stm32

Tags: c++, stm32

I have an 32-bit ARM Cortex M4 ([the processor in Pixhawk](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-pixhawk-overview.html)) to write two classes, each one is one threading in Pixhawk codebase setting.
The first one is **LidarScanner**, which dealing with incoming serial data and generates "obstacle situation". The second one is **Algorithm**, which handle "obstacle situation" and take some planning strategy. Here are my solution right now, use the reference function **LidarScanner::updateObstacle(uint8_t (&array)[181])** to update "obstacle situation" which is 181 size array.

**LidarScanner.cpp**:

```
class LidarScanner{

private:
    struct{
        bool available = false;
        int  AngleArr[181];
        int  RangeArr[181];
        bool isObstacle[181] = {};  //1: unsafe; 0:safe; 
    }scan;

    ......   
public:
    LidarScanner();

    //main function
    void update()
    {
        while(hal.uartE->available())       //incoming serial data is available
        {
            decode_data();                  //decode serial data into three kind data: Range, Angle and Period_flag

            if(complete_scan())             //determine if the lidarscanner one period is completed 
            {
                scan.available = false;     
                checkObstacle();            //check obstacle situation and store safety in isObstacle[181]
                scan.available = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //for another API recall
    void updateObstacle(uint8_t (&array)[181])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=181; i++)
        {
            array[i]=scan.isObstacle[i];
        }       
    } 
    //for another API recall
    bool ScanAvailable() const { return scan.available; }
    ......
}
```

**Algorithm.cpp:**

```
class Algorithm{

private:

    uint8_t Obatcle_Value[181] = {};

    class LidarScanner& _lidarscanner;
    ......

public:

    Algorithm(class LidarScanner& _lidarscanner);

    //main funcation
    void update()
    {
        if (hal.uartE->available() && _lidarscanner.ScanAvailable())
        {
            //Update obstacle situation into Algorithm phase and do more planning strategy
            _lidarscanner.updateObstacle(Obatcle_Value); 
        }
    }

    ......
}`
```

Usually, it works fine. But I want to improve the performances so that I want to know what's the most effective way to do that. thanks!!!!

Comment: Does the data need to be copied?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to copy data is to use the DMA.

```
DMAx_Channelx->CNDTR = size;
DMAx_Channelx->CPAR = (uint32_t)&source;
DMAx_Channelx->CMAR = (uint32_t)&destination;
DMAx_Channelx->CCR =  (0<<DMA_CCR_MSIZE_Pos) | (0<<DMA_CCR_PSIZE_Pos)
                      | DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_PINC | DMA_CCR_MEM2MEM ;
while(!(DMAx->ISR & DMA_ISR_TCIFx ));
```

[AN4031 Using the DMA controller.](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/27/46/7c/ea/2d/91/40/a9/DM00046011.pdf/files/DM00046011.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00046011.pdf)

Comment: DMA is not well suited for memory-to-memory copies. Especially when the data doesn't even need to be copied…

Comment: @duskwuff The processor is even worse in copying data (twice as slow). The data might not need to be copied, correct. But that is unclear.